# Cardinal Arithmetic $a^ba^c = a^{b+c}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that for any cardinal numer $a,b,c$ that $a^b a^c = a^{b+c}$.

Start with three non-empty sets $A,B$ and $C$ such that $A∩B=\emptyset$,and show that $|A|^{|B|} \dot |A|^{|C|} = A^{|B| + |C|}$

Workings:

This would be done by establishing a bijection between $A^B \times A^C$ and $A^{B \cup C}$

But I'm not sure what the bijection could possible be.

Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I know of this [Notation on proving injectivity of a function $f:A^{B\;\cup\; C}\to A^B\times A^C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80105/notation-on-proving-injectivity-of-a-function-fab-cup-c-to-ab-times-a).

But that uses notation and concepts I am not familiar with.

Comment: There is a natural candidate of a bijection: consider the map $(f,g)\mapsto f\cup g$. If $B$ and $C$ are disjoint, then $f\cup g$ is a function from $B\cup C$ to $A$ (why?)

Comment: You may regard $f$ as a set of pairs, so the notation $f\cup g$ works and sometimes it defines a new function.